# how to play video in the background?

Tags: windows

how to play video in the background? I have a hdmi to hdmi cable connected from the pc to tv. I would like to play. All is working and that I can play video from my pc to tv but the problem is I need to use my computer while the video is still playing from my pc to tv in order to do other work on my computer. Is there a way to play the video in the background using my browser to play the video?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which operating system you're using but you should be able to enable a multi-monitor display. It's under display and appearance in windows. This will allow you to use the two screens for independent reasons.

Comment: Then try this guide: http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/windows-vista/2008/01/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-windows-vista